# Video sharing app written in rails

Tags: web-apps, open-source, video, web-development

I'm looking for a video sharing app like:

- http://clip-bucket.com/
- http://www.phpmotion.com/

But I want an open source app written in ruby on rails, I don't care about the default features,  I could add features, I don't care about the app being lightweight or not, I could buy more powerful servers. Must run on Linux obviously.

- User registration and accounts
- Video uploading
- More features is a plus, but it's okay, if  they don't exist.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations Stack Exchange! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.

Comment: @DanteTheEgregore no everything is there per rules:
**What kind of application are you looking for?** I already said, **What operating system do you want the application to run on?** obviously linux. I don't care about the hardware, I can buy bigger servers if needed, **What features must the application have?** , video sharing, something like youtube or vimeo and I gave 2 examples in case my explanation wasn't enough, tell me what information do you want exactly and I will edit my question, my goal and requirements are listed above

Comment: Your question still does not fit within our minimum quality guidelines. I recommend you read both the question and the corresponding answer in their entirety and try looking at a few example questions here on SR.

Comment: @DanteTheEgregore I tried

Comment: I search for the same thing, too. The closest I could get is [OwnTube](http://owntube.org) but it's python and I'm to dumb to get in running. Eventually I will start my own thing but I essentially need a "private youtube" which, in the best case, can also handle images and audio.

Comment: @2called-chaos thank you, I know some python, I think I'll use that for now, I don't like php, nor smarty template nor tbs

Answer (score 1):

It is not Ruby but YouPHPTube! is an video-sharing website, very easy to install

The software allow you to upload, view, share and comment on videos, and it makes use of WebM and H.264/MPEG-4 AVC to display a wide variety of user-generated and corporate media videos.

Best of all, YouPHPTube! is an open source solution that is freely available to everyone.

http://www.youphptube.com/

Comment: Great Tip, there is on YouPHPTube a video tutorial teaching how to install it: http://tutorials.youphptube.com/video/how-to-install-youphptube-in-a-fresh-ubuntu-server